# I want to make sure that users can put numbers only from 1 - 10 in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, validation

*This is the code for the textformfield I want to restrict.  Users should only be able to enter values from 1-10 but I cant find how to implement that*

```
       TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter the Overall Rating';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ], // Only numbers can be entered
                maxLength: 2,
                maxLengthEnforced: true,
                controller: overall,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Overall Rating  Out of /10",
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check the given string is a less than 11 you can do it with the help you a validator. but when using a validator you need to perform a trigger or an event need to take place
If you want to run your code that way you can use this code ...

**Code with using validator(Using tigger or even)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Textfi extends StatelessWidget {
  Textfi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 70,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter the Overall Rating';
              } else if (int.parse(value) < 1 || int.parse(value) > 10) {
                return 'The rating must be between 1 and 10';
              }
              return null;
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ], // Only numbers can be entered
            maxLength: 2,
            maxLengthEnforced: true,

            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Overall Rating  Out of /10",
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('Validation done')),
                );
              }
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 80,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: const Center(child: Text("Submit")),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**If you want to check the value in real time**

you can't use a validator you need to restrict your input value the only way to do that is using `inputFormatters:`

in your case you are using inputFormatter as:

```
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
```

which will only input digits

> If you want to input a restricted number you need to make use of **Regex**

for that change your

```
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
```

to

```
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[    
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("^(1[0-0]|[1-9])\$")),
            ],
```

*This will help you to only enter only numbers from 1 to 10 : -*

**RegExp("^(1[0-0]|[1-9])$")**

**Full code **

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Textfi extends StatelessWidget {
  Textfi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 70,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter the Overall Rating';
              } else if (int.parse(value) < 1 || int.parse(value) > 10) {
                return 'The rating must be between 1 and 10';
              }
              return null;
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("^(1[0-0]|[1-9])\$")),
            ],
            // inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            //   FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            // ], // Only numbers can be entered
            maxLength: 2,
            maxLengthEnforced: true,

            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Overall Rating  Out of /10",
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('Validation done')),
                );
              }
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 80,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: const Center(child: Text("Submit")),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me.  Apologies for the late response.  My android studio was giving me issues so I had to reinstall it

Comment: can you make this answer acceptable (as correct )

Comment: sure sure.  Sorry about that.  I forgot.  Thanks again

Comment: can you also upvote the answer so that more people can make use of the answer

Answer (score 2):

inside the **inputFormatters** : you simply put below express and this should work...

*// regex expression to accept number only from 1-10*

```
inputFormatters: [  
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[1-9]$|^10$'),
),],
```

Answer (score 1):

you can update your validator function as follows

```
validator: (value) {
   if (value.isEmpty) {
     return 'Please enter the Overall Rating';
   }
   if(int.parse(value) < 1 || int.parse(value) > 10) {
      return 'The rating must be between 1 and 10';
   }

   return null;
},
```

Comment: It gives me an error for the '<' and '>' .  The error is The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'String'.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with form and for digit validation, you need to parse the string to int

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
              ],
              // Only numbers can be entered
              maxLength: 2,
              maxLengthEnforced: true,
              controller: overall,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Overall Rating  Out of /10",
              ),
              validator: (text) {
                if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Text is empty';
                }
                if (int.parse(text) < 1 || int.parse(text) > 10) {
                  return 'The rating must be between 1 and 10';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // TODO submit
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```