# How to Restricting user input in text field flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text field where I want to limit the user input for a range. e.g. I want the first number is zero the second number is  three or four . How can I achieve this in the text field? I can't find any argument to set this.

my code

```
TextFormField(
                         textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                         enableSuggestions: false,
                         autocorrect: false,
                         maxLength: 12,
                        inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                         keyboardType: TextInputType.number)
```

** Addition :
i add this instruction but not working , what is the problem now

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'^(?:[0][3-4])?[0-9]{12}$')),
```

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155299/allow-only-specific-input-in-textformfield-without-validation-in-flutter

Comment: thank you I've edited my answer.but i still have a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a mask  or changing the onChanged value.

Try:

```
onChanged: (value) => {
  int n = int.parse(value)??0;
  int oldN = int.parse(myController.text.substring(0,1))??0;

  switch(oldN){
    case 0:
       if (n != 2 || n != 3){
         myController.text =  myController.text.substring(0,myCobtroller.lenght-1);
       }
  }
}
```

In this example, If First number is 0 and next number is different of 2 or 3 the controller don't be changed.

...

Edit I Create a complete example for you here:
https://gist.github.com/sergiotucano/7738517c264b672da7ea6a15e676d231

Comment: thank you I've edited my answer.but i still have a problem

Comment: you tried my code example? Because the flutter and the component textformfield don't have any solution that can do it in this way that you want.  If you use an package mask with dynamic mask change maybe you can get to the result.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it shows some errors that I don't understand.                                 
error1: Expected to find '}'. at   int n = int.parse(value)??0;                                                  error2: Expected to find ','. at   int n = int.parse(value)??0;                                                   error3: error: Undefined name 'n'.  at  n=int n = int.parse(value)??0;

Comment: Sorry man. I Edit my answer to put a git link check the link .

Answer (score 0):

**This will be working fine:**

```
TextFormField(
                             textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                             enableSuggestions: false,
                             autocorrect: false,
                             maxLength: 12,
                            inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("^0[34][0-9]*$")),],
                             keyboardType: TextInputType.number)
```